# ASP.net Core Application Entity Framework 6 not generating database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created an `ASP.net` Core web Application (`.NET Framework`) application and added the Entity Framework 6 to the project.

I have also created my `DB context` as follows:

```
namespace application1
{

    Class _Dbcontext : DbContext
    {
       DbSet<Item> item {get; set;}
       DbSet<ItemView> itemView {get; set;}
     }
}
```

I have created the models as follows:

```
Class Item 
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    List<ItemView> ItemViews {get; set;}
}

Class ItemView
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public Item item {get; set;}
}
```

I have also followed the article found [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html)  to set up the project.

when I run the project the database is not generated in the `mssqllocaldb` or `(localdb)/ProjectsV13`.

I can use help knowing how to set up the `ASP.NET` core Web Application (.NET Framework) template to use `Entity Framework 6`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It sounds like you are not creating the database and assume that it should be "generated" for you. There should be *something* that could trigger this generation, and none of the code that you posted would do that.

Answer (score 0):

The database is not created until you make the first request to the database: login to the website or the data request. Or you could use special command in the nuget package console:

```
> update-database
```